# Unable to fit entire webpage content in webview when first initialized?

Tags: android, html, webview

As stated in the title I'm trying to fit entire webpage shown in the code below into this [GitHub WebView](https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android) however, it only show part of the webpage when it first initialize and I have to manually zoom out in order to scale the webpage to see the entire webpage content. Tried `.webViewLoadWithOverviewMode(true).webViewUseWideViewPort(true)` to no avail. Please help Thank you!

```
String url = "http://livedemo.mbahcoding.com/ajax_crud_datatables_images_upload";
                new FinestWebView.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .webViewLoadWithOverviewMode(true)
                        .webViewUseWideViewPort(true)
                        .webViewBuiltInZoomControls(true).show(url);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are some extra options to tweak your webview's initial zoom setting.

```
 setInitialScale(1);
```

Sets the webview to the furthest zoom. Can be really ugly at times.

```
setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Seems to zoom far enough so your page is viewable.

Comment: I'm using an this github library https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/FinestWebView-Android to implement my webview. I can't seems to find this 2 option.